# Posts are not getting fetched on TimeLine Page (Flutter App)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Google Firebase to store and fetch User Posts. But this code is not fetching user posts on the timeline page. Please help me out. I have tried a lot of methods, but I am not getting what is the error.

This code is working fine for fetching users to follow.

```
final usersRef = Firestore.instance.collection('users');

class Timeline extends StatefulWidget {
  final User currentUser;

  Timeline({this.currentUser});

  @override
  _TimelineState createState() => _TimelineState();
}

class _TimelineState extends State<Timeline> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  List<Post> posts;
  List<String> followingList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTimeline();
    getFollowing();
  }

  getTimeline() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await timelineRef
        .document(widget.currentUser.id)
        .collection('timelinePosts')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();
    List<Post> posts =
        snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
    setState(() {
      this.posts = posts;
    });
  }

  getFollowing() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followingRef
        .document(currentUser.id)
        .collection('userFollowing')
        .getDocuments();
    setState(() {
      followingList = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => doc.documentID).toList();
    });
  }

  buildTimeline() {
    if (posts == null) {
      return circularProgress();
    } else if (posts.isEmpty) {
      return buildUsersToFollow();
    } else {
      return ListView(children: posts);
    }
  }
```

// this is working fine

```
buildUsersToFollow() // haven't mentioned fully because it was working fine

@override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text(
      'Social Media App',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: "Signatra",
        fontSize: 50.0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () => getTimeline(), child: buildTimeline()),
    );
  }
}
```

I would be very happy and thankful if this issue of mine will get resolved.

Comment: You mentioned getting an error, could you provide that as well?

Comment: Sir not an error sorry. But List<Post> posts is empty. No posts are getting added to it. Could you please help me? what's wrong am I doing!!!

Like if I print, print(posts), in the terminal it's showing [], which means nothing is getting fetched into it.

Answer (score 0):

rather than that it must show instance of that snapshot if its not showing the instance of snapshot then it is not accessing the server . and use then function at the time of accessing in the function getTimeline()

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('users')
.doc(userId)
.get()
.then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
    print('Document exists on the database');
  }
});
```

try to refactor like this that is given in a official doc
[Firebase Official Doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage)